# App crashes on launch due to runtime errors

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am new to android development(weeks old) and trying to create an app which sets phone screen Wallpaper as the ImageView.

Things I have done:

- Try to set the Wallpaper without using Bitmap.
- Try to run without "onClick referring to another method"
- Search online for the exact problem but failed.
- Tried to delete the .gradle folder and rebuilding my project.
- Resolved every warning by letting Android Studio to steer warnings.

LogCat :

> Process: com.example.wallpaper_vault, PID: 29859
> **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wallpaper_vault/com.example.wallpaper_vault.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference**
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2692)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
> **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference**
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:149)
> at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
> at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:579)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
> at com.example.wallpaper_vault.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:19)
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1083)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6517) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)

Java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView srcWpFull = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wpFull);
    Button srcSetWp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setWp);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        srcWpFull.setImageResource(R.drawable.angdev);
        Log.e("erronCreate", "in onCreate()");
        srcSetWp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               setWallpaper();
        }
        });
    }

    private void setWallpaper() {
        Log.e("errsetWallpaper", "in setWallaper()");
        Bitmap srcBit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.angdev);
        WallpaperManager srcManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        try{
            srcManager.setBitmap(srcBit);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

XML :

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wpFull"
        android:layout_width="414dp"
        android:layout_height="221dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/wallpaper"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/angdev" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setWp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/set_wallpaper"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wpFull" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am sorry for any mistakes cause this is my first post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking carefully in your logs you will observe that it is pointing you to a MainActivity line -19 here

`androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223) at com.example.wallpaper_vault.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:19) at`

The problem is you are initializing your image view and your button before onCreate. You can't use a context before onCreate is called. That's the reason it's giving you `NullPointerException`.

Write this two lines

```
ImageView srcWpFull = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wpFull);
Button srcSetWp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setWp);
```

after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in your onCreate method and you're good to go.

Comment: I was hoping the problem to be a of higher degree than this Thanks brother!

Comment: Hahah. this is the common issue faced by everyone at early stage. Just try to read error logs as much as possible it will always point you to something helpful. Also if this answer helped please do a upvote so other's can find easily.